# How should I use mixed effects modeling with 3 factors?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

I have a research problem and already collected the data from experiments.

Suppose, I plan to study the relationship between variable `X` (independent variable) and variable `Y` (dependent variable). I also consider the impacts of three distinct factors `A`, `B`, `C`, each factor has two levels (`A = 0` or `A = 1`) as dummy variable. Therefore, I have `2*2*2=8` different experiment scenarios in the experimental design. The same group of participants take all eight experiments.

I plan to specify the model in R using `lme4` as

```r
model <- lmer(
    data = dataset,
    formula = Y ~ 1 + X + A + B + C + (1 + X | Scenario) + 
                  (1 + X | Participant)
)
```

I have three problems regarding the model formulation of mixed effects model in my research problem?

**1. Does the model formulation make sense?**

Besides `X` as the independent variable, I also take dummy variables `A`, `B` and `C` as independent variables to study their impacts on estimating `Y`. I consider `Scenario` and `Participant` as the random effects? I am curious whether it is possible to take dummy variables `A`, `B` and `C` as fixed effects and `Scenario` as random effect at the same time. Because it seems `Scenario`  includes `A`, `B` and `C`. Do I understand this right?

**2. What other forms of model can I consider?**

Based on this base model, I plan to add other terms:

- interaction terms of `A`, `B` and `C` on `X`.
- The crossed structure of random effects between `Scenario` and `Participant`. From [Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified), I think there is crossed random effects in my problem.
- Maybe other covariates like the gender/age of participants.

But I think that the model would be too complex and am not sure whether the model would perform well or not.

**3. What is the differences in results of using three-way ANOVA and mixed effect model in this problem?**

And the final question is what's the advantage of using mixed effects model over three-way ANOVA? I understand I can get a generalized regression model for different scenario setting combinations which is nice. But my focus is on the impact of `A`, `B`, `C` on the relationship between `X` and `Y`. Do I analyze by just comparing the slopes and intercepts (the estimated coefficients)?